# Block certain websites on Ubuntu for main user

Tags: internet, websites

I have a problem with some kind of Internet addiction. I want to block some sites on my Ubuntu 12.04 for myself. Changing DNS and `/etc/hosts` doesn't help couse I know pass and any time when I find myself frustrated I can chenge dns back and after that find myself searching through the stupid websites rather than work.

Is there any solution? Maybe some type of a programm where I need to enter a long password to change settings of Internet connetion. And this password will differ from my login pas which I always use. And I can stash this long pass far from me in a deep dark wood buried in a hole...

Comment: Ultimately, *anything* you implement locally, you'll be able to disable or override as root. You can make it take a lot of effort but the only way to avoid this entirely is to have a machine involved for which you do not know the root password. It is in the very nature of root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution could be, as it is written here: [Block Websites with Nonsudo Password](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1771763), to use [Net Responsibility](http://www.netresponsibility.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/), you can configurate it for your router and set up a long router password, and ask a friend to keep this pass. (If you use router.)

Comment: Thanks for answer. But what if a have no router? Is it possible to make some hack just on a Linux?

Comment: Change your DNS settings on your computer so they point to OpenDNS.

Comment: The only one thing that prevent me from changing DNS settings back is my root pass that I khow well. I'm saying about another password that can guard Internet settings.

Comment: I found this: [Block Websites with Nonsudo Password](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1771763), which point to [this](http://www.netresponsibility.com/).

Comment: Whooo! Greate. It looks like you've found the way to help me. Thanks a lot. Can you write a new answer with this info so I can mark it as accepted?